# C++/WinRT - process exited with code -1073741819

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I am using [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) to access the `HumanInterfaceDevices` API from Microsoft. I get

> `process exited with code -1073741819`

when trying to call the `GetDeviceSelector` API. The program terminates for some reason, but I'm unable to understand why.

What's the issue with the following code and how do I fix it?

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::HumanInterfaceDevice;

int main()
{
    //uint16_t const pid[] = { 0xBA0, 0x5C4, 0x09CC }
   
    init_apartment();
  
    int const product = 0x09CC;
    int const vid = 0x054C;
    int const usagePage = 0x01;
    int const usageId = 0x02;

    IHidDeviceStatics hello;
  
    try {
        printf("trying");
        winrt::hstring data = hello.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vid, product);
    }
    catch (...) {
        printf("error\n");
     
    } 
}
```

Comment: `-1073741819` is access violation: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741819](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741819)

Comment: You are calling `GetDeviceSelector` on a null pointer (`hello`). You can just call the static method `HidDevice::GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vid, product);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the code under a debugger you'll get an exception message in the debug output window along the lines of:

> Exception thrown at <some address> in <program>.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

when evaluating the following expression:

```cpp
hello.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vid, product)
```

The code is trying to read from address zero. That address isn't mapped into any process, raising an Access Violation (SEH) exception with error code `0xC0000005` (that's the hexadecimal representation of `-1073741819`; use the [MagNumDB](https://www.magnumdb.com/) if you need quick help with any numeric error code on Windows).

`hello` here is a default-constructed `IHidDeviceStatics` object, a C++/WinRT smart pointer type holding a `nullptr`. Dereferencing it will consequently trigger the Access Violation exception.

That said, you rarely ever need to interact with `IXyzStatics` interfaces; C++/WinRT deals with that for you already, and instead provides static class members on the corresponding projected Windows Runtime type (`HidDevice`)<sup>1</sup>.

The fix is simple:

```cpp
winrt::hstring data = HidDevice::GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vid, product);
std::wcout << data.c_str() << std::endl;
```

produces the following output:

> System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{4D1E55B2-F16F-11CF-88CB-001111000030}" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND System.DeviceInterface.Hid.UsagePage:=1 AND System.DeviceInterface.Hid.UsageId:=2 AND System.DeviceInterface.Hid.VendorId:=1356 AND System.DeviceInterface.Hid.ProductId:=2508

---

<sup>1</sup> *This is somewhat involved. Raymond Chen covered this in [On static methods in the Windows Runtime and C++/WinRT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210524-00/?p=105240).*